# C in Swift Project

Tags: ios, c, swift

I'm not too familiar with trying to use C functions from an external library in a Swift project.

I have the following code (commented with the necessary typedefs):

```
    func sadp40() {
        let start: Int32 = SADP_Start_V40(SadpDataCallBack, 0, nil) // <-- Error occurs here.
    }
    
    func SadpDataCallBack(lpDeviceInfo: SADP_DEVICE_INFO_V40?, pUserData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> () {
        // debugPrint(lpDeviceInfoV40?.struSadpDeviceInfo.szIPv4Address as Any)
    }
    
    /*
    typedef void (CALLBACK *PDEVICE_FIND_CALLBACK_V40)(const SADP_DEVICE_INFO_V40 *lpDeviceInfo, void *pUserData);
    CSADP_API BOOL CALLBACK SADP_Start_V40(PDEVICE_FIND_CALLBACK_V40 pDeviceFindCallBack, int bInstallNPF, void* pUserData);
     */
```

In the function `sadp40()` I'm receiving a `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` error but I'm not sure how to fix it or why it is occurring.

Edit:

Option + Click in XCode:

[image: Option + Click in Xcode]

Comment: What’s the imported type of SADP_Start_V40? (I.e. when you option click it in Xcode)?

Comment: @Alexander I have edited the question with the func declaration.

Comment: I asked for the _imported type_, I.e. what Swift actually sees from the clang importer

Comment: @Alexander I have edited it with the direct option + click from XCode, although they are exactly the same.

Comment: @SamuraiMelon, at the very least, the type of `SadpDataCallBack` (that is the function itself, via its signature, rather than the type it returns) doesn't match `PDEVICE_FIND_CALLBACK_V40`, because that's going to be a C function pointer, and by default Swift functions aren't.   You could at `@convention(c)` in front of definition of `SadpDataCallBack`, or you could pass a closure as the first parameter to `SADP_Start_V40` that calls `SadpDataCallBack`.

Comment: If `SadpDataCallBack` is an instance method in some type, that's going to be a problem because those take an implicit `self` parameter that C won't know about.  Either make it a free function, or a `static` method, *and* either mark it as `@convention(c)` or use a closure like `SADP_Start_V40( { SadpDataCallBack($0, $1, $2) }, 0, nil)`  The Swift compiler knows about C function pointer arguments, so it should automatically make the closure have the right type.  Just don't capture anything or use any instance methods in it.

Comment: You could alternatively make `SadpDataCallBack` a closure variable.  Something like `let SadpDataCallback: PDEVICE_FIND_CALLBACK_V40 = { (lpDeviceInfo, userInfo) in ... }` should work.

Comment: Oh I didn’t see that first image you posted. It’s like 3 pixels tall and essentially invisible on mobile. As always, post code as code, and that’s yet another reason why :)

Comment: “Just don't capture anything or use any instance methods in it.”, you couldn’t if it you tried, `@convention(c)` will block that.

Comment: Thank you for all the help @Alexander. I've posted what XCode seems to be happy with in the edit.

Comment: Thank you for all the help @ChipJarred. I've posted what XCode seems to be happy with in the edit.

Comment: Please post it (as code! stop with the screenshots! Arg!) as an answer to your own question. After 24h, you can mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: I've changed it from a screenshot to code, which I should have done first, my apologies! I cannot post an answer as the question is closed...

Comment: @SamuraiMelon, I'm glad our input helped you arrive at a solution!

Comment: Do not modify a question to include its own answer.

Comment: @matt I had to because it was, I believe incorrectly, closed so no answers can be accepted.

Comment: But what I say is still true. If you can't give the answer as an answer then you can give it as a comment or remain silent. But do not include it in the question.